# Sending image from php to html via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have a PHP function to generate an image:

```
function gen_img(){
$image = imagecreate(200,200);
.... //some php codes
header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);
}
// there is no problem when generating image, image generated successfully when i call the function
```

I know how to put it at the html using this :

```
<img id='imageone' src="link to the function">
// the image shown, loaded in the <img> tag, no problem
```

but, now i want the image loaded using jquery ajax and then put it into `<img>` tag.
Can someone tell me the way please?

Comment: Why like that? The moment you place the html tag into the dom the browser will load the image automatically. Why go through the bother of base64 encoding the image data?

Comment: i want the image be refreshed, and it is random image. it most like a captcha

Comment: ah. Well, I would go with base 64 encoding the image data. See my answer

Comment: you can have an AJAX call which will go to your php backend and return the new image url. Upon success of your AJAX call, update the <img> tag with this new url.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest base64 encoding the image data

```
$data = imagecreate(200,200);
$type = 'jpeg';
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
echo $base64;
```

in the javascript part you should be able to do:

```
document.getElementById('captha').src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh............................. etc...';
```

full fledged example:

```
<img src="blank.gif" id="captha">
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.ajax('captha.php?ident=xyhksj78').done(function(data){
      document.getElementById('captha').src=data;
      });
</script>
```

Comment: error with this message :  base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: You'll have to use a file reader of somesort to have this working.
Most examples read a file from disk and implement that read file into the base64.

Answer (score 0):

> i want the image be refreshed, and it is random image. it most like a captcha

Still no need to use AJAX.

Simple set a new `src` attribute value for the image element. You can f.e. add the current timestamp value as a query string parameter, so that the browser will request it again from the server, and not fetch it from its cache:

```
$('#imageone').attr('src', 'scriptname.php?' + (new Date).getTime());
```

Done …